# ExecutorService MultiThreading on sql server

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

i'm building a java app to import data from sql server  database  to Elastic Search i'm using ExecutorService with Callable to make threads every thread take page number also using pool connection.
i notice that one thread only run in database  i want threads to run parallel  not series

```
  int count=  Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); ;
    ExecutorService asyncExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(count);
    List<Future<List<json>>> list = new ArrayList<Future<List<json>>>();
    Future<List<json>> ml = null;
    List<json> jList = null;
    CutrePool c = new CutrePool(DBL.DB.URL2, DBL.DB.USER, DBL.DB.PASS);
    do {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Therads1 t = new Therads1(page, PageSize, c.getConnection());
                ml = asyncExecutor.submit(t);
                list.add(ml);
                page += 1;
            }
            for (Future<List<json>> j : list) {
                jList = j.get();
                if (!(jList == null)) {
                    asyncExecutor.execute(new Therads0(jList));
                    System.out.println(" count in elastic   " + BL.es.pLcount);

            }
      }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNf7E.png)

Comment: i'm added image to for this please can view it

Comment: What does it mean? I don't know this UI.

Comment: sql server monitor show one thread only is running  other threads ideal

Comment: Did you check [this](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) out? Also because of your assumptions that more threads may be more ideal?